# iOS AVFoundation's AVCapturePhotoOutput

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avfoundation, avcaptureoutput

I am trying to move away from AVCaptureStillImageOutput and to adopt **AVCapturePhotoOutput**, which was introduced in iOS 10.

However, my deployment os is iOS 9.0.  Would AVCapturePhotoOutput still run on iOS 9?

Comment: No, to run on iOS 9 you will need to keep the old `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` in your code. Using `AVCapturePhotoOutput` on iOS 9 will most likely cause a crash.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because `AVCapturePhotoOutput` was introduced in the iOS 10 SDK and hence that class is not available in SDK's older than this. If you are required to maintain backwards compatibility for iOS 9, you'll have to do a bit of extra work until you can drop support. In Swift, you can use the built-in `#available` syntax:

```
if #available(iOS 10, *) {
    // use AVCapturePhotoOutput
}
else {
    // use AVCaptureStillImageOutput
}
```

This allows you to act appropriately depending on which version of iOS a given installation of your app runs on.